# use of c# nested class and accessiblity

Tags: c#, oop

i am aware of nested class. how could i design my nested class in such way that out side of parent class of nested class no one will be able to access nested class like instance create etc because i want the child class will be private. i want to expose my child class property, method everything by parent class property or method. please guide me to write the code for such kind of nested class. thanks

```
public class Person
{
private string _firstName;
private string _lastName;
private DateTime _birthday;

//...

public class FirstNameComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x._firstName.CompareTo(y._lastName);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mark the internal class as `private` instead of `public`.

```
public class Person
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private DateTime _birthday;

    private FirstNameComparer firstNameComparer = new FirstNameComparer();

    public int CompareFirstNames(Person x, Person y)
    {
       return firstNameComparer.Compare(x, y);
    }

    //...

    private class FirstNameComparer : IComparer<Person>
    {
        public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
        {
            return x._firstName.CompareTo(y._lastName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also add a GetComparer or Compare method to your outer class to answer the second part of the OP's question ("i want to expose my child class property, method everything by parent class property or method"), otherwise +1

Comment: @dash Added a property for that.

Comment: child class FirstNameComparer has no constructor....so the default constructor will work behind the scene. default constructor is public by default.

Comment: Public members inside a private nested class are only visible to the containing class. Try it, you won't be able to access the default public `FirstNameComparer` constructor from outside `Person`.

Comment: This solution is completely wrong. If you want to access this from different dll, I wish you good luck. However you will fail.

Comment: So I finally tried this out in Visual Studio, it turns out the property I exposed had an error with accessibility levels, so I replaced it with a private instance and a method that exposes the same functionality, tested and working even through a referenced assembly.

Answer (score 2):

you can make the nested class `private`. The main class will be in charge of creating the nested class instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use private accessor for nested class. If you want to expose some of its properties, you can create new property for main class like this :

```
private FirstNameComparer _FirstNameComparer = new FirstNameComparer();
public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return _FirstNameComparer.Compare(Person x, Person y); 
    }
```